# Cocoa: enterFullScreenMode with transparent background

Tags: swift, cocoa, fullscreen, transparent

Is there a possibility to have a NSView in fullscreen-mode with a transparent background window, like a transparent overlay over the underlying desktop?

```
view.enterFullScreenMode(view.window!.screen!, withOptions: nil )
view.window!.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.01)
```

I can set the color of the view's window, but there always seems to be another black window behind it.

Comment: I think the underlaying desktop is black (because a new one is created). This can be seen during the animation. Is this something you want (see new empty desktop)?

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I would like to see the original desktop instead of the new empty desktop. But it sounds like I need another approach for this.